# JS - React - map() method filter on element index (only run if index meets condition)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, arraylist

I've got a list I want to iterate trough. And based on it's index it should do something.
it filters it on:

- if index == 0
- if index is above 0 && lower than half array.length
- if index is above half array.length

Right now I have the following code. And it is working. But it's not effecient. Since it iterates though the entire array 3 times. Is there a way to filter this?

Core of the problem:

```
            block.blockGrid.map((blockItem, index) => {
              if (index > 0 && index <= (newArrayLength / 2)) {
                <BlockGridElementFirstHalf key item={blockItem} index={index}/>
              }
            })
```

Entire code:

```
class BlockGrid extends React.Component {

    render() {
      let {block} = this.props;

      const newArrayLength = (block.blockGrid.length % 2 === 0) ? block.blockGrid.length : block.blockGrid.length + 1;

      return (
        <React.Fragment>

          <Row>

            <Col xs={6}>
              {/*only run element 0 */}
              {block.blockGrid &&
              block.blockGrid.map((blockItem, index) => {
                if (index === 0) {
                  return <BlockGridElementZero key item={blockItem} index={index}/>
                }
              })}

              {/* only run element from 1 to half of length */}
              {block.blockGrid &&
              block.blockGrid.map((blockItem, index) => {
                if (index > 0 && index <= (newArrayLength / 2)) {
                  <BlockGridElementFirstHalf key item={blockItem} index={index}/>
                }
              })}
            </Col>

          </Row>

          <Row>

            <Col xs={6}>

              {/* only run element from half of length up to last */}
              {block.blockGrid &&
              block.blockGrid.map((blockItem, index) => {
                if (index > (newArrayLength / 2)) {
                  <BlockGridElementLastHalf key item={blockItem} index={index}/>
                }
              })}

            </Col>

          </Row>
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check this code snippet ?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ygwbah

You can filter a map like this:

```
myArray
    .filter((el, i) => (i === 0 ))
    .map((element, index) => {
      // do my code
    })
  }
```

Comment: Perfect, it works. Could you add `  block.blockGrid
    .filter((el, i) => (i > 0 && i < (newArrayLength / 2)))
    .map((blockItem, index) => {
      return <BlockGridElementFirstHalf key item={blockItem} index={index}/>
    })
  }` to the answer? This way it's easier for future reference

Comment: I've added the third condition ==> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ygwbah

Comment: Thanks, I've added a edit answer suggestion to make it more clear for future reads here. To make it clear the answer lies in the `.filter()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if this helps. It will iterate through your items only once -

```
 class BlockGrid extends React.Component { 
    render() {
      let row1 = [], row2 = [];
      block.blockGrid && block.blockGrid.forEach((element, i) => {
        if (i == 0) {
          rows1.push(<BlockGridElementZero key item={blockItem} index={i} />);
        }
        else if (i > 0 && i <= (newArrayLength / 2) {
          rows1.push(<BlockGridElementFirstHalf key item={blockItem} index={i} />);
        }
        else {
          rows2.push(<BlockGridElementLastHalf key item={blockItem} index={i} />);
        }
      });
      return (
        <>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={6}>
              {row1}
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={6}>
              {row2}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Have not thought of it. But I think this approach makes it one step less readable.

Comment: Yes true. It might make it less readable but you will achieve it in one iteration.